# With vue-chart.js , Can pass chart type as a property?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-chartjs

With vue-chart.js , Can pass chart type as a property?
Want example source code. Please teach me.

Comment: We'll be glad to help you when you will reach a problem. Meanwhile we're not here to teach neither give free code (this is consider as a "do my job" question). Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Make your research try things and when you face a specific problem come back ;-)

Answer (score 0):

vue-chartjs author here,

no that is not possible. The concept of vue-chartjs is that you have individual components you import. You have the `Line` component for the line chart, the `Bar` component for the bar chart and so on.

You can then add the component as a mixin to your chart component or use `extends`. So it is not possible to change the chart type on the fly or pass it as a prop.

You can however create custom chart types / new chart types.

http://vue-chartjs.org/#/home?id=custom-new-charts